# ++i "does not exist in current context" when trying to increase variable in C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Trying to control a variable in a script from another script in C# however when I reference it and try to get it to increase the value by one, I get the error of "The name i does not exist in current context."

Whole code unit would be

```
        //Update enemy amount
    GameObject theManager = GameObject.Find("EnemyManager");
    AutomaticDifficultyManager managerScript = theManager.GetComponent<AutomaticDifficultyManager>();
    AutomaticDifficultyManager.amountOfEnemies ++i;
```

This seems like such a simple fix yet for some reason it's not clicking why I can't get it to simply increase the variable by one count.

Comment: Are you trying to increment `amountOfEnemies` or is there another variable named `i` that you want to increment?

Comment: Are you missing an assignment operator, or is that just a typo in the question?

Comment: Did you declare i ?

Comment: You probably just need `++AutomaticDifficultyManager.amountOfEnemies`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you want to increase the value stored within `amountOfEnemies`?

The code for that would be `++managerScript.amountOfEnemies`.

There is a difference between the `++` in front of a variable and after it. If you prepend the `++`, essentially what happens is, the value gets increased first and is then used. If you postfix the `++`, the value as is is used, and increased afterwards.

As an example:

```cs
int x = 0;

int newValue = ++x;
// newValue now has the value of 1 and x as well.

int nextTry = x++;
// nextTry is now still at 1 while x is at 2.
```

Comment: Why do values being referenced through a different script need to be placed in front of variable not after? How is this difference significant enough to make the code not work if wrong way round.

Comment: The issue was not that your code was the wrong way around, the issue was the `i` in the end - it does not belong there, it's an example name of a variable. In fact it's like the general example variable name you use when working with integers. Your code will work as well if you do `managerScript.amountOfEnemies++`, just don't add that `i` or a space ;)